# spring data mongodb MappingException twitter4j.MediaEntityJSONImpl$Size

Tags: spring-data, spring-boot, twitter4j, spring-data-mongodb

Right now we are using Spring Boot(1.1.9.RELEASE), Spring Data, MongoDB and Twitter4J to store tweets.

When tweets arrive we are able to store these into MongoDB. All good!

However, when we try to read the tweets back from MongoDB using Spring Data we get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: 
No property json found on entity class `twitter4j.MediaEntityJSONImpl$Size` 
to bind constructor parameter to!
```

This is because, I believe, that the `twitter4j.MediaEntityJSONImpl` doesn't have a default constructor. As you can see below:

```
    public class MediaEntityJSONImpl extends EntityIndex implements MediaEntity {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3609683338035442290L;
        private long id;
        private String url;
        private String mediaURL;
        private String mediaURLHttps;
        private String expandedURL;
        private String displayURL;
        private Map<Integer, MediaEntity.Size> sizes;
        private String type;

        MediaEntityJSONImpl(JSONObject json) throws TwitterException {
        ...
        ...
        }
}
```

So:

1. How do I fix this issue? Since Twitter4J classes are not under our control I cannot use the `@PersistenceConstructor`. Am I right?
2. Do I need to write a custom `MappingMongoConverter`? Yes, I have read the reference document but I cannot envisage how to write one for this Twitter4J object? Do I need to write a reader and a writer?
3. Are we taking the wrong approach? That is, when a tweet comes in should we be mapping/converting the `Twitter4J Status` object into a similar `Status` object in our domain? As we would have more control over our domain classes so we can provide default constructors or `@PersistenceConstructor`.

Any help and code examples would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
GM